# How to limit query in price filter

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, limit

How to limit query to 6 in woocommerce product price filter short-code [products_by_price min="100" max="300"]? The code below is based on woocommerce product short-code which unfortunately does not support **per_page**. In this case I need to limit query to 6 to avoid showing all products.

```
add_shortcode( 'wc_products_price_range', 'wc_products_price_range' );
function wc_products_price_range( $atts, $content, $shortcode ) {
    if ( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) {
        $shortcodes = new WC_Shortcodes();
        if ( is_array( $atts ) ) {
            $min = (int) $atts['min'];
            $max = (int) $atts['max'];
            if ( $min && $max ) {
                $and = "meta_value BETWEEN $min AND $max";
            } else {
                if ( $min ) {
                    $and = "meta_value >= $min";
                } elseif ( $max ) {
                    $and = "meta_value <= $max";
                }
            }
            if ( $and ) {
                global $wpdb;
                $query = "SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_price' AND $and";
                $ids = $wpdb->get_col( $query );
                if ( ! empty( $ids ) ) {
                    $atts['ids'] = implode( ",", $ids );
                }
            }
        }
        return $shortcodes->products( $atts );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a quick scan of WC shortcode class I have came across this :

```
public static function products( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'columns' => '4',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order'   => 'asc',
        'ids'     => '',
        'skus'    => ''
    ), $atts );
```

it means you can pass 'column' attribute along with ids where you can limit posts per page.

and in this query :

```
   $query = "SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_price' AND $and";
```

you can use limit 0,6 with order by clause.
Hope this helps.
OR

random rows:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id >= (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(id) * RAND()) FROM `table` ) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;
```

or you can pass 'rand' to attributes in shortcode.

Comment: Works great with the limit
'$query = "SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_price' AND $and limit 0,6";'
but it shows only first 6 results from the database. Is there a way I can show any 6 results? Cheers!

Comment: try select floor(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(post_id) FROM wp_postmeta)) from wp_postmeta limit 6